# how can we add a row span attribute in a table cell using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and each row has a class assigned to it. Based on this class I want to add a row span to the first column of all the rows with that class name. e.g.
I have a html table as below

```
<table id="myTestTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1" class="A">
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="A">
            <td>A</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" class="B">
            <td>B</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4" class="B">
            <td>B</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" class="B">
            <td>B</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I need to convert it like

```
<table id="myTestTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="1" class="A">
            <td rowspan="2">A</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="A">

            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3" class="B">
            <td rowspan="3">B</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4" class="B">

            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5" class="B">

            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I know we need to use the row span attribute like this `$('Selector').attr('rowspan', 'n');`and we can use the jquery length property to count the number of rows with a certain class `$(".a").length)` but can't figure out how to solve this particular problem.

Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? you are in the right direction, usually when you start typing the solution will just come to you.

Comment: Do you know the class names hat will be on the `tr` elements before you perform this operation? I'm just figuring out if you can build an array to loop over, or would need to traverse the DOM to check each `tr` individually.

Comment: I will know the class names of the rows where I want to add  row span

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of finding the first row with class A/B, and then modifying the first td's rowspan to be the number of rows with the A/B class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a_length = $('#myTestTable .A').length;
  var b_length = $('#myTestTable .B').length;

  $('#myTestTable .A').first().find("td:first").attr('rowspan', a_length);
  $('#myTestTable .B').first().find("td:first").attr('rowspan', b_length);

  $('#myTestTable .A, #myTestTable .B').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (!$(obj).find("td:first").attr("rowspan")) {
      $(obj).find("td:first").remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTestTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1" class="A">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" class="A">
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" class="B">
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4" class="B">
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="5" class="B">
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Zack. You have put me in the right direction. The last thing which I need to do is to remove the first table cell from the rest of the rows after applying the row span in the first row.

Comment: No prob. Basically I just looped through all table rows and if the first td has doesn't have a rowspan (which would indicate we didn't append a rowspan to it), I removed it.